# flashback recovery in oracle 10g

Tags: oracle10g, recovery, flashback

i m using oracle 10g and i want to enable flashback database
i hava manually run all the command like

```
SQL> shutdown immediate;
SQL> startup mount;
SQL> alter database archivelog;

SQL> ALTER SYSTEM SET DB_FLASHBACK_RETENTION_TARGET=4320;

SQL> ALTER SYSTEM SET DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST_SIZE=536870912;

SQL> ALTER SYSTEM SET DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST='/C/TEMP1';
SQL> ALTER DATABASE OPEN;
SQL>ALTER DATABASE FLASHBACK ON;
```

it shows the error like

```
ORA-00439: feature not enabled : Flashback Database
```

plz anyone can help me to setup the flashback database?

Comment: I believe you need to `ALTER DATABASE FLASHBACK ON` *before* you `ALTER DATABASE OPEN`.

Comment: http://psoug.org/reference/flash_db.html

Comment: Your steps are correct, but the Oracle Software Edition doesn't support this Feature! Try Enterprise Edition!

Answer (score 2):

Jeffrey Kemp's comment is correct.  `ALTER DATABASE FLASHBACK ON` cannot be specified while the database is open.  SQL Reference manual states:  "You can specify this clause when the database is mounted but not open."

Comment: You can enable flashback database after a clean shutdown and your DB in Mount (or Open) - cite "Ensure the database instance is open or mounted" in Chap7 - Oracle doc 12c Backup & Recovery manual. The problem with the question is "VERSION" not enable flashback database feature!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely is that you are not using the Enterprise Edition.
Do you happen to be on Standard Edition or XE ?

Ronald - who thinks this question fits better in http://dba.stackexchange.com